A contiguous ${}_3F_2(1)$ hypergeometric identity?
I stumbled upon a curious identity that seems to hold for all integers $n\ge3$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}\prod_{j=1}^i{-{n-3j\choose3}\over{n\choose3}-{n-3j\choose3}}
={n\over3}\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}\prod_{j=1}^i{-{n+2-3j\choose3}\over{n\choose3}-{n-3j\choose3}}.$$
(The left-hand side multiplied by ${n\choose3}!$ counts the number of ways to order the $3$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ so that each set after the first one contains some element of a previously chosen set; see https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2023.105776 for details.)
In terms of hypergeometric functions, this states that
$$f(3,4,5)={n\over3}f(1,2,3),\tag{$*$}$$
where
$$f(a,b,c):={}_3F_2\biggl({a\over3}-{n\over3},{b\over3}-{n\over3},{c\over3}-{n\over3};
{1\over6}\bigl(9-3n+X_n\bigr),{1\over6}\bigl(9-3n-X_n\bigr);1
\biggr)$$
and $X_n=\sqrt{1+6n-3n^2}$. Note that we can prove
$${n\over3}f(1,2,3)={n-1\over3}f(0,2,4)={n-2\over3}f(0,1,5)$$
by proving that $f(0,1,2)=0$ and using contiguous hypergeometric identities; in turn we can prove that $f(0,1,2)=0$ by considering the determinant of a Hessenberg matrix:
$$f(0,1,2)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}\prod_{j=1}^i\frac{-\binom{n+3-3j}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}-\binom{n-3j}{3}}
=\quad=\prod_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{3}-\binom{n-3j}{3}}\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
\binom{n}{3}&\binom{n}{3}-\binom{n-3}{3}&0&\cdots&0\\
0&\binom{n-3}{3}&\binom{n}{3}-\binom{n-6}{3}&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&\binom{n}{3}-\binom{n-3\lfloor n/3\rfloor}{3}
\end{pmatrix}=0.$$
In fact, I can prove ($*$), since $f(1,2,3)$ is balanced / Saalschützian and so is summable by the Pfaff–Saalschütz identity, and the left-hand side yields after applying some ${}_3F_2(1)$ transformations and manipulating.
My proof is quite tedious and indirect, and I think there should be a nice proof, since $f(3,4,5)$ and $f(1,2,3)$ are contiguous. But I've been unable to get any contiguous identities to work for this problem. Maybe the answer lies in the determinant form of this identity.
Question

How do I prove ($*$) ‘directly,’ perhaps by using contiguous hypergeometric identities?


Note that the zero identity also generalizes: For $n\ge t\ge1$ we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/t\rfloor}\prod_{j=1}^i\frac{-\binom{n+t-tj}{t}}{\binom{n}{t}-\binom{n-tj}{t}}=0.$$

First, we convert the desired identity into equivalent forms:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}(-1)^i \left\{ \prod_{j=1}^i{{n-3j\choose3}\over{n\choose3}-{n-3j\choose3}}
-\frac{n}3\, \prod_{j=1}^i{{n+2-3j\choose3}\over{n\choose3}-{n-3j\choose3}}\right\} & = 0 \\
\iff 
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} (-1)^i  (3i)!  \left\{ \binom{n-3}{3i} -\frac{n}3 \binom{n-1}{3i} \right\} \prod_{j=1}^i {1\over3![{n\choose3}-{n-3j\choose3}]} & =0 \\
\iff 
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} (-1)^i (3i)!  \left\{3 \binom{n-3}{3i} -n \binom{n-1}{3i} \right\}
 \prod_{j=i+1}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} 3! \left[{n\choose3}-{n-3j\choose3}\right] & =0.
\end{align}
At this point, by introducing an indeterminate $x$, we propose a generalization
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} (-1)^i (3i)!  \left\{3 \binom{x-3}{3i} -x \binom{x-1}{3i} \right\}
 \prod_{j=i+1}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} 3! \left[{x\choose3}-{x-3j\choose3}\right] = \prod_{k=3}^{3\lfloor\frac{n+3}3 \rfloor}(k-x).$$
Now, we make the \it harmless \rm substitution $n\rightarrow 3n$ and aim at proving
$$f(x;n):=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i (3i)!  \left\{3 \binom{x-3}{3i} -x \binom{x-1}{3i} \right\}
 \prod_{j=i+1}^n 3! \left[{x\choose3}-{x-3j\choose3}\right] = \prod_{k=0}^{3n} (k+3-x).$$
Induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ is straightforward. Assume $f(x;n)=\prod_{k=0}^{3n} (k+3-x)$ and consider
\begin{align}
f(x;n+1)&=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^i (3i)!  \left\{3 \binom{x-3}{3i} -x \binom{x-1}{3i} \right\}
 \prod_{j=i+1}^{n+1} 3! \left[{x\choose3}-{x-3j\choose3}\right] \\
%&=3! \left[{x\choose3}-{x-3n-3\choose3}\right] \times \\
%& \qquad \times \left\{\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^i (3i)!  \left\{3 \binom{x-3}{3i} -x \binom{x-1}{3i} \right\}
% \prod_{j=i+1}^n 3! \left[{x\choose3}-{x-3j\choose3}\right] \right\} \\
&= (-1)^{n+1} (3n+3)!  \left\{3 \binom{x-3}{3n+3} -x \binom{x-1}{3n+3} \right\} + 3! \left[{x\choose3}-{x-3n-3\choose3}\right] \times f(x;n)  \\
&=(-1)^{n+1}   \left\{ 3\prod_{k=0}^{3n+2}(x-k-3) - x\prod_{k=0}^{3n+2} (x-k-1) \right\} \\
& \qquad \qquad \qquad + 3! \left[{x\choose3}-{x-3n-3\choose3}\right] \times \prod_{k=0}^{3n} (k+3-x)  \\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\left\{ 3(x-3n-4)(x-3n-5)- x(x-1)(x-2) \right\} \times \prod_{k=0}^{3n}(x-k-3)  \\
& \qquad\qquad + \left[x(x-1)(x-2) - (x-3n-3)(x-3n-4)(x-3n-5)\right] \times \prod_{k=0}^{3n}(k+3-x) \\
&=(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{3n+1} \left\{ 3(x-3n-4)(x-3n-5)- x(x-1)(x-2) \right\} \times \prod_{k=0}^{3n}(k+3-x)  \\
& \qquad\qquad + \left[x(x-1)(x-2) - (x-3n-3)(x-3n-4)(x-3n-5)\right] \times \prod_{k=0}^{3n}(k+3-x) \\
&= [3(x-3n-4)(x-3n-5)-(x-3n-3)(x-3n-4)(x-3n-5)]\times \prod_{k=0}^{3n}(k+3-x)  \\
&=[(3n+4-x)(3n+5-x)(3n+6-x)]\times \prod_{k=0}^{3n}(k+3-x) \\
&= \prod_{k=0}^{3n+3}(k+3-x),
\end{align}
as desired. We now discern that the OP's identity is the special case $x=3n$ leading to
$$f(3n;n)=\prod_{k=0}^{3n}(k+3-3n)=0$$
and hence the proof is complete here. $\square$
Postscript. It seems that the OP's claim can be generalized:
For all integers $n\ge t$, we have the identity
$$\pmb{ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/t\rfloor}(-1)^i \prod_{j=1}^i{{n-tj\choose t}\over{n\choose t}-{n-tj\choose t}}
= \frac{n}t \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/t\rfloor}(-1)^i  \prod_{j=1}^i{{n+t-1-tj\choose t}\over{n\choose t}-{n-tj\choose t}}}. $$

That's pretty nice; I like the generalization. Thanks for your help!

You are very welcome.

Does the same proof work for the identity generalized from $3$ to $t$? (Also, the ${n-3t\choose t}$ in its denominator should be ${n-t j\choose t}$.)

I believe it does. Also, your comment is right, will fix it.
